# Why does the location of an event change the time at which it happend? Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

So if you use the boost transformation to find the time an event happend you need to use the distance the event happend from the current observer, why is that? How can the distance from the observer change the time that it took for an event to happen?

Answer (score 0):

A single event is just $(t_0,x_0)$ in one frame and $(t_0',x_0')$ in another, so there's not much to be said.

You're really asking about the simultaneity of two events, which is of course, relative. If the primary frame is $U$, then viewed from the origin $O=(0,0)$, a simultaneous event occurs anywhere at $E=(0,x_0)$...something $U$ may refer to as *now*.

In the frame moving, $U'$, at $v$ then:

$$ O = (0,0)'$$
$$ E =(-\gamma v x_0, \gamma x_0)'$$

The time coordinate in $U'$ depends linearly on $x'$:

$$t_0' = -vx_0'$$

This is clear from the Minkowski diagram, in which the locus of $t'=0$ is the $x'$ axis:

[image]

That's the Lorentz transformation. "why" is somewhat subjective, but one could pin it on the invariant interval:

$$\Delta s^2 = \Delta t^2 -\Delta x^2 $$

In $U$, $\Delta t= t_0-0 =0$, so:

$$\Delta s^2 =  -x_0^2 $$

Hence, in $U'$:

$$\Delta s^2 =  t_0'^2 -x_0'^2 = -x_0^2 $$

Plugging in the relation between $x'_0$ and $x_0$ gives:

$$ t_0'^2 -x_0'^2 = -(x_0'/\gamma)^2 $$

or

$$ t_0'^2  = -x_0'^2(1 - \frac 1 {\gamma^2}) = -v^2x_0'^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Since time is measured by clocks. Clocks are physical objects which obey physical laws. Special relativity says how these objects are affected by things like velocity which can affect how fast the components of a clock can move. Thus it shouldn't be too suprising (well it was surprising at the time) that moving a clock from one location to another will affect the time shown on the clock.

So if you have some clocks all set to the same time, then move them to different locations, well then the distance you moved the clocks will have some effect on the time they show.

Comment: Time dilation has nothing to do with how fast the components of a clock can move.

Comment: How fast *relative* to other clocks. By components I mean even the vibrations of the very atoms themselves.

Comment: There's nothing vibrating inside a muon, but the lifetimes of cosmic ray muons are dilated from the perspective of observers on Earth.

Comment: @J.Murray The phase of a muon wavefunction changes with time. So it depends on your definition of vibrate I suppose.